# Reinstall Windows with CD-ROM not booting?

Tags: windows-vista, bios, restore

I was given an old Acer Aspire 5100 laptop with Windows Vista.  It ran so slowly that I decided I would try running Chromium OS on it instead to "turn it into" a Chromebook.  I tried installing CloudReady from Neverware.  I can boot CloudReady from the USB just fine, but it seems to never install and won't ever boot into a Chromebook-like experience.  But by letting CloudReady wipe my hard drive, it no won't longer boot at all past a blank black screen.

What I'm having trouble with is ***going back!***  No matter what boot order I create in BIOS now, I can't get Windows to reinstall.  I suppose CloudReady wiped out more than I thought it would.  How can I install Windows on basically a blank hard drive when the CD won't boot?  I can't find how to get into any sort of Command Prompt and just force it to wipe completely clean or back to factory?

I do NOT care about any files -- I'm ok with erasing EVERYTHING.  And before anyone comments -- yes it's a legitimate version Windows.  *(Who would steal Vista anymore anyway?!)*

Answer (score 1):

You should still be able to install Windows with a blank hard drive.

You will need to check the BIOS to disable settings such as 'Secure Boot' and 'Fast Boot' - if your BIOS supports UEFI, you might need to select the alternative option or enable 'Legacy Boot' or 'Legacy BIOS'. All of these settings can be changed back once installed. Make sure USB boot is top of the boot options and make sure you save your changes!

When you say you can't get Windows to reinstall, is it even detecting the USB after BIOS?